# Pure REST & Exponential Backoff possible?

Tags: api, rest

Is there a way to implement exponential backoff on a *pure* REST API? You'd have to keep track of some state (e.g. IP Address, account), no?

Comment: In REST, it is OK to keep state on the server before a request completes. It's not OK to keep state between requests. Your question is too vague, but if you can implement the algorithm in a single call, there's nothing wrong with REST. Also, what is "pure" REST? :)

Comment: @Slavo By "pure" REST I meant the server doesn't keep state between requests, like you said. I'm not implying anything is wrong with REST, I am just wondering how to implement exponential backoff without keeping track of the number of tries between requests, because that would violate REST (unless it doesn't!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the **client's** responsibility to implement a backoff policy, as far as I am concerned. Otherwise, as you said, some sort of state must be maintained, such as checking a cookie, request token, etc.

Now, by that definition, many REST APIs are not *pure* since they take request tokens as parameters and may restrict the number of calls per hour or day, but that is the tradeoff.

Comment: I don't agree that the backoff is the client's responsibility, because  an attacker could simply use any other client to bypass the throttling.

Comment: That is true. If you want to be able to handle that, you're trading theoretical purity for practical security. Nothing wrong with that, but your requests are not idempotent at that point -- they have an arbitrary side effect of delaying the result.